# Transfer Learning in Encoder-Decoder Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, model

Here is the list of layers my model (mT5) has:

```
shared.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.relative_attention_bias.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
encoder.block.0.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
encoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
encoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
encoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
encoder.block.1.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.1.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
encoder.block.1.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
encoder.block.1.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
encoder.block.1.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
encoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
encoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
encoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
encoder.block.2.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.2.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
encoder.block.2.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
encoder.block.2.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
encoder.block.2.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
encoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
encoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
encoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
encoder.block.3.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.3.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
encoder.block.3.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
encoder.block.3.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
encoder.block.3.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
encoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
encoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
encoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
encoder.block.4.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.4.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
encoder.block.4.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
encoder.block.4.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
encoder.block.4.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
encoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
encoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
encoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
encoder.block.5.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.5.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
encoder.block.5.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
encoder.block.5.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
encoder.block.5.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
encoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
encoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
encoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
encoder.block.6.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.6.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
encoder.block.6.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
encoder.block.6.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
encoder.block.6.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
encoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
encoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
encoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
encoder.block.7.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
encoder.block.7.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
encoder.block.7.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
encoder.block.7.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
encoder.block.7.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
encoder.final_layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.relative_attention_bias.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
decoder.block.0.layer.2.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
decoder.block.1.layer.2.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
decoder.block.2.layer.2.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
decoder.block.3.layer.2.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
decoder.block.4.layer.2.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
decoder.block.5.layer.2.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
decoder.block.6.layer.2.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.0.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.1.layer_norm.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight
decoder.block.7.layer.2.layer_norm.weight
decoder.final_layer_norm.weight
lm_head.weight
```

If I want to use Transfer Learning, which layers should I freeze?

Do I need to freeze both encoders and decoders?

My initial thoughts were to freeze both encoders and decodes, blocks 0,1,2, and maybe 3.

My mission is to fine-tune mT5 model on a QA dataset for QA generation.

Comment: Food for thought: Why freeze? Cos save training time to convergence. Q: Why not train everything without freezing? Cos not enough training time to train? Q: How much time does it save with frozen layers? No sure. Q: What if we dont freeze any layers? Takes longer to converge. Q: How many or which layer to freeze? Empirical, only definitive proof is to sweep through a hyperparameter grid search where the hyperparameter is "which layer to freeze"? Consider this last food for thought, what if you dont freeze any layers =)

Comment: TL;DR. There's only one definitive way to know which layers to freeze and it's by hyperparameters sweep through "which layer to freeze". Also, it'll depends on what data it's trained on, how it's cross-validated and what other hyperparams are swept during training.